# why php.ini file path not same?

Tags: php

console:

**`# php -i|grep php.ini`**

Configuration File (`php.ini`) Path => `/usr/local/lib`

web:

**`phpinfo()`**

;
Configuration File (`php.ini`) Path => `/usr/local/php/etc`

why is the path not the same?

Answer (score 0):

`php -i|grep php.ini` returns with the path used for **CLI** applications

`phpinfo()` shows the php.ini path used for **WEB** applications (configured in the web server's php module configuration)

Comment: we must keep 2 php.ini files yet?